# Equivalent of RUBY has_many and belongs_to relationship in Java

Tags: java, ruby, has-many, belongs-to

Normally to realized linked objects, i usually use getter and setter methods and this way i add objects of different type to another object.

Now i have come across this Ruby Structure, e.g:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments 
end 
class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :article 
end
```

Can you tell me what is the equivalent of this `has_many` and `belongs_to` in Java. Basically i want to translate some similar data structure from Ruby to Java.

Comment: These methods are specific for Ruby's `ActiveRecord` [ORM framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). Specify what ORM are you using in Java project (Hibernate, Spring...)?

Comment: Thanks @AlexKliuchnikau for pointing out. I am still a newbie, guess i will have to read through the ORM frameworks for java first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highly depends on the ORM you're using. Most (I assume) people will go with Hibernate in java. With Hibernate you have the possibility to annotate relationships quite similar.

`@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations seem to be those which you might have to take a closer look at.

Article class:

```
public class Article {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "belongsTo")
    private List<Comment> comments;
    [...]
}
```

Comment class:

```
public class Comment {
    @ManyToOne
    private Article belongsTo;
    [...]
}
```

If you want to use another ORM, I'm afraid I can't help you out :)

Comment: thank you, actually i have not much experience with ORM of any sort, so i will have to go through the documentation.

Comment: If the original post is from one of your projects, it should not be too difficult to learn java ORM frameworks :) I highly recommend having a look at hibernate :)

Answer (score 1):

An `Article` has a collection of `Comment`s. Each `Comment` has a reference to its `Article`.

If you're asking about a specific ORM you need to indicate which one.